# Python3, using openpyxl to read cells

Tags: python-3.x, printing, openpyxl

Thank you, Tc Zhong, for helping! The correct way to print the value is print(cell[0].value)

---------Here is the original question------------------

I am currently learning python to read from xlsx format spreadsheet, and I downloaded openpyxl. This is my function：

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook(filename = 'List.xlsx', data_only = True)
lst = book.active
def give_cell (workbook, start: str, end: str):
    cell_range = workbook[start:end]
    for cells in cell_range:
        print (cells.value)
```

When I run this in my python shell:

```
give_cell(lst, 'D3', 'D5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
  File "/Users/Sophie/Documents/google search", line 7, in <module>
    print (cells.value)
builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

it tells me that 'tuple'object has no attribute 'value', but I don't understand why it does not have attribute 'value', or why 'print(cells.value)' does not work. I initially tried print(cells), but it will not return the value in cells, but rather something like

```
(<Cell 'lst'.D3>,)
(<Cell 'lst'.D4>,)
(<Cell 'lst'.D5>,)
```

I am not so sure what is going on. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it shows, it is a tuple, you need to use `cells[0].value` to access the first element of this tuple.

Comment: Please accept answer if it solved your problem by clicking the tick button next to the answer. Thanks

Comment: You mean you put a `return` in the for loop? It will only return the first element. If you want all result, you could save them in a list.

Comment: I figured it out :) Thank you very much!